# Set binding value as a parameter on a behavior from another control value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, behavior

I am trying to validate a entry value using the entry behaviors. In order to do that I need to pass the value to behavior class from another control in the same xaml.

I have below two controls

```
    <Entry
    x:Name="RegisterQty"
    Grid.Column="0"
    WidthRequest="120"
    TextChanged="RegisterQty_TextChanged"
    TextColor="Black"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    PlaceholderColor="Black" 
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    FontSize="20">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
           <local:RegisterQtyBehavior LoadQty = "{Binding BindingContext.qty, Source={x:Reference RegisterQty}} "/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>

    </Entry>

public class RegisterQtyBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{        
    public static readonly BindableProperty LoadQtyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LoadQty), typeof(double), typeof(RegisterQtyBehavior), 0);

    public double LoadQty
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LoadQtyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadQtyProperty, value); }
    }
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        double result = LoadQty;

        bool isValid = double.TryParse(args.NewTextValue, out result);
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = isValid ? Color.Red : Color.Default;
    }
}
```

I want to pass label binding Qty to entry control. How could i achieve this? Adding directly `LoadQty = "{Binding Qty}"`
does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to parameter in entry behaviors using binding, am I right? if yes, I do one sample you can take a look:

```
   <Entry x:Name="registerqty">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <local:RegisterQtyBehavior LoadQty="{Binding BindingContext.qty, Source={x:Reference registerqty}}}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>

        </Entry>

public partial class Page37 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _qty;
    public int qty
    {
        get { return _qty; }
        set
        {
            _qty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("qty");
        }
    }

    public Page37 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        qty = 100;

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class RegisterQtyBehavior:Behavior<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LoadQtyProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LoadQty", typeof(int), typeof(RegisterQtyBehavior), defaultValue: 0);

    public int LoadQty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LoadQtyProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LoadQtyProperty,value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //double result;
        //bool isValid = double.TryParse(args.NewTextValue, out result);
        //((Entry)sender).TextColor = isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewTextValue))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(args.NewTextValue) > LoadQty)
            {
                ((Entry)sender).TextColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Entry)sender).TextColor = Color.Default;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting this error No property, bindable property, or event found for 'LoadQty', or mismatching type between value and property

Comment: @Zeeshan, I have no error when I run my project, do you see **RegisterQtyBehavior class**, inheriting **Behavior<Entry> class**, there is **BindableProperty LoadQty** in this class

Comment: Yes, I have followed same code as you have given in your example still i am getting type exception on runtime, I have edited my code kindly check.